Retrieve list of desktop flows and actions in those flows in Power Automate Desktop using Powershell and WebAPI
How to retrieve the list of desktop flows and list of actions in those flows for a particular environment in Power Automate Desktop using Web API in powershell?
I'm new to powershell and power automate.
